# Webscrape using Python and BeautifulSoup - Error Message unsure how to fix

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to write a script that will scrape the Name, Role, and Phone numbers of real estate agents from this [website](https://www.raywhite.com/contact/?type=People&target=people&suburb=Sydney%2C%20NSW%202000&radius=10&firstname=&lastname=&_so=people). It works for the first 30 or so people, but then the error message comes up:

```
role = agent_role[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"card horizontal-split vcard"})

for container in containers:
    agent_name = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-name"})
    name = agent_name[0].text

agent_role = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-role"})
role = agent_role[0].text

filterfn = lambda x: 'href' in x.attrs and x['href'].startswith("tel")
phones = list(map(lambda x: x.text,filter(filterfn,container.findAll("a"))))

print("name: " + name)
print("role: " + role)
print("phones:" + repr(phones))
```

I understand the problem is that my script is getting stuck on the real estate agent who's role isn't listed, however I am unsure how to make it overcome this and continue for the rest of the agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a if condition and check if the role is there

```
agent_role = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-role"})
if len(agent_role) > 0: 
   role = agent_role[0].text
else:
   role = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the `agent_role` list is "truthy".

```
agent_role = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-role"})
role = ''
if agent_role:
    role = agent_role[0].text
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
role = agent_role[0].text if agent_role else ''
```

Comment: Clean and effective code, but consider using `find` if you only need the first match